# Read access control solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity, modifiers

Let's say that we have a contract that not anyone can access to view function :

```solidity
contract AccessControl {
    mapping (address => bool) authorized;

    function getSomething () public view returns (string) { 
        // control if the caller is authorized
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I tried this but it works only on javascript-vm (remix)

```solidity
contract AccessControl {
    mapping (address => bool) authorized;

    function getSomething () public view returns (string) { 
        require(authorized[msg.sender]);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: Contract looks OK.  What problems do you have with it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, blockchain is public, and everyone may read code of your contract and storage of your contract, so there could not be anything private there.

Access control you suggest will only work when function is called from within another smart contract.

Comment: so isn't possible ?

Comment: For public blockchain you cannot prevent off-chain applications and humans from reading data of your contract.

Comment: I wont prevent them from reading data, I want to prevent them from calling a function

Comment: You cannot prevent people from calling your function off-chain, and there is no much sense to call `view` function on-chain, unless it is called from another contract.

Comment: Ok, So I will add a digital signature to verify access

Comment: It's pointless to guard read-only functions in a contract. It merely inconveniences a determined adversary.

Comment: Not really.  Consider oracle contract that is able to return accurate and reliable ETH/USD exchange rate.  For off-chain applications and humans this information costs nothing because it is public anyway, but for other smart contracts this information is valuable and oracle smart contract may restrict read access to only those contract whose creators paid money to the owner of oracle contract.